# Unmarshalling yaml

Tags: go, yaml

I'm having an issue trying to read in this yaml using *gopkg.in/yaml.v2* The error is:

`line 1: cannot unmarshal !!seq into main.Owners`

Reading file:

```
content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("apartments.yml")

owners := Owners{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal(content, &owners)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
}
```

My struct looks like:

```
type Owners struct {
    Owner []struct {
        Apartment  string `yaml:"apartment"`
        PaymentIds []string `yaml:"paymentIds"`
    } `yaml:"owner"`
}
```

Data:

```
- owner:
    apartment: 002
    paymentIds:
      - KB002
- owner:
    apartment: 003
    paymentIds:
      - KB003
- owner:
    apartment: 004
    paymentIds:
      - KB004
- owner:
    apartment: 005
    paymentIds:
      - KB005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use struct slice of `Owners` not `Owner` since there is `owner` node for every `Owners` according to your `yaml`.

```
type Owners []struct {
    Owner struct {
        Apartment  string `yaml:"apartment"`
        PaymentIds []string `yaml:"paymentIds"`
    } `yaml:"owner"`
}
```